# Ubuntu terminal commands and usage

Tags: application-development, command-line, c++

I just got Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday and would like to learn how to use the terminal.

The reason why is because I'm a developer and I'm trying to get any applications I develop supported on linux. From what I understand the teminal is a big part of developing on linux.

If any information is needed I'm programming in C++ in the Code::Blocks IDE.
I'm having troubles finding tutorials on how to use it, especially for development cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the community

I started using Ubuntu about a year ago, until this day i consider myself still in the very basic stages of learning about it, its long way but its worth it and fun.

The best place to learn about the terminal commands and bash language is the terminal itself, evertime you have doubts about a command or just want to learn more about it you can simple use the `man` (manual) command, i.e. `man mount` and it will output, as the name says, a manual about the desired command, you can also use `-h` and `--help`.

I recommend you read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal?action=show&redirect=BasicCommands), provided by the [community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/) and also the [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/) site which breaks down any command line you input and explains each part individually.

I hope this is enough to get you started, cheers.